# Retrieval-augmented generation without OpenAIEmbeddings

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, langchain

I'm playing with HuggingFace and some of the models on there. I'm trying to achieve something along the lines of [RAG](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/). Seems like a pretty clear guide with all the needed ingredients and recipe. But the cooking sequence is what I need help.

What I want to do:

- Have a question and answer chat app
- But the chat app will depend on custom information given the model to answer some specialized questions.

Thus

- the model will 100% reside on HuggingFace and "inferred" (I hope I'm using the term right) remotely from a VPS using HuggingFace client
- and the VPS will locally have the custom documents used for the "indexing" and "fine tuning"

**What I've done**

With that in mind, here's what I've been able to do so far in the past couple of days (see python script below)

But the problem I keep encountering is, EVERY article/tutorial/documentation I've come across so far CANNOT write 3 sentences without mentioning something along the lines of OpenAI* *sigh*

I do not want to use ANYTHING OpenAI (is that even possible?)

Below is my python script.

```
import os
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from huggingface_hub import InferenceClient

# <rant>
# Where to import what from seems to be a whack-a-mole sport with this 
# langchain project. They can't seem to keep a module at a location
# even for a few version upgrades straight. Woow!

os.environ['HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN'] = 'hf_xx'
# os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'sk-xx' # I don't wanna use anything OpenAI*

import gradio as gr

# Load openchat model
openchat = InferenceClient(model="openchat/openchat_3.5", token='hf_xx')
documents = ["trainingData/pdfs.pdf"]

# Define embedding function
def extract_embedding(document):
    # Extract embedding using OpenAIEmbeddings
    embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings.embed_query(text=document)
    return embedding

# Load document embeddings
document_embeddings = [extract_embedding(document) for document in documents]

# Load vectorstore index
index = FAISS.from_documents(documents=documents, embeddings=document_embeddings)

# Define LLM chain
llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=openchat)

# Create RagChain manually
def predict(docs, input):
    # Retrieve relevant documents from index
    retrieved_docs = index.query(input)

    # Run LLM chain on retrieved documents
    outputs = []
    for doc in retrieved_docs:
        output = llm_chain.predict(input=doc)
        outputs.append(output)

    return outputs

# Launch Gradio app
iface = gr.Interface(fn=predict, inputs="text", outputs="text").launch()
```

How far off am I from the mark? And how do I get on track?

Currently, when I run the above script, I get the error:

```
TypeError: OpenAIEmbeddings.embed_query() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Like mentioned earlier, I'd prefer not to use OpenAI anywhere in the script above, so any alternatives are welcomed.

Will appreciate any insights

Comment: Why do you import `OpenAIEmbeddings` when you don't intend to use it? From a technical perspective, you can build your application without OpenAI. However, you might face an issue from the performance perspective because the model you use needs to be capable of producing meaningful embeddings. That means you can not just a transformer model, it needs to be one that was trained to produce meaningful sentence-embeddings.

Comment: Some more details on the issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64237402/6664872). To fix your error, you need to use a different embedding object. Please check the [documentation](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/api_reference.html#module-langchain.embeddings) for alternatives.

Comment: @cronoik `> Why do you import OpenAIEmbeddings when you don't intend to use it?` Yes, I was following the docs. I just needed to get it running to begin with, the the next refinements could happen. But that was also throwing the above issue I had

Comment: @cronoik thanks for the pointers. I see plenty options. I'm inclined to go with the `embeddings.huggingface.HuggingFaceEmbeddings` in my use case regarding my choice of the `openchat_3.5` model. At this point of my experimentations, speed/performance isn't much of a concern. I'm geared towards getting it working, then I'll move onto the next steps of improving the various parts involved

Comment: I see a few other embeddings from HuggingFace. Will read on them to see which one would match best to the text generation model I'm using. Thank you. Really appreciate.

Comment: AFAIK, none of the hf embedding classes will work for you with your model. I just checked the documentation but haven't tested it myself. For openchat you might want to look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76926025/sentence-embeddings-from-llama-2-huggingface-opensource/77441536#77441536) and write your own function.

Comment: huggingface is an absolute disaster..

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos it's an absolute disaster because...? What do you think is a better alternative?

Comment: The codebase is dirty, most implementations are inefficient, updates are frequently breaking compatibility, and it's the epitomy of an open source project turned into a distribution monopoly. There's not many alternatives, unfortunately. When I can't avoid using it, the way I approach it is to find the bare minimum necessary components that I need and cannot replicate, isolate them, and wrap my code around them.